# CentOS 7 doesn't show first two drives on intel C606 SCU

Tags: centos, hard-disk, storage, intel

I am using a SuperMicro X9SRi-3F motherboard, which uses the Intel C606 chipset and has a dual 4-port SCU with SAS capability. The HDDs I'm using are 4x WD Re's (WD6001F9YZ), and 2x WD Gold's (WD6002FRYZ). All are 6TB in capacity.

The WD6001F9YZ's are connected to ports 0-3, and the WD6002FRYZ's are on ports 4&5 (should be noted, I will eventually be adding two more WD6001F9YZ's to ports 6&7).

OS is installed on a 1TB drive connected to one of the normal SATA 2.0 ports on the board.

CentOS 7 can recognize all the drives, as `lsblk` outputs the following:

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   5.5T  0 disk 
sdb               8:16   0   5.5T  0 disk 
sdc               8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk 
sdd               8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk 
sde               8:64   0   5.5T  0 disk 
sdf               8:80   0   5.5T  0 disk
```

They also all show up under `/dev/disk/by-id`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:06 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA58PYRS -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:06 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LV7KR -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:06 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LV87E -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:06 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVL4J -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:06 ata-WDC_WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B0_K1HNL2KD -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:06 ata-WDC_WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B0_K1JMY3ND -> ../../sdf
```

However, only drives c-f show up in `/dev/disk/by-path`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 13:42 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x500304801349fe00-lun-0 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 13:42 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x500304801349fe01-lun-0 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 13:42 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x500304801349fe02-lun-0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 13:42 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x500304801349fe03-lun-0 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 13:42 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy0-lun-0 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 13:42 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy1-lun-0 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 13:42 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 13:42 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy3-lun-0 -> ../../sdd
```

In the MB's BIOS, when the SCU unit is enabled and the "SCU RAID Option ROM/UEFI Driver" is enabled, all of the drives are recognized:

[image: Option ROM Enabled]

When the SCU unit is enabled, but the Option ROM is disabled, the drives do not show up in the BIOS:

[image: Option ROM Disabled]

Both settings (Option ROM Disabled/Enabled) result in the same issue. Of course, disabling the SCU means it doesn't show up in the OS at all (disappears from the output of lspci)

The output of `lshw -c storage` looks like this:

```
*-sas                     
   description: Serial Attached SCSI controller
   product: C606 chipset Dual 4-Port SATA/SAS Storage Control Unit
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: scsi6
   logical name: scsi7
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: sas pm pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=isci latency=0
   resources: irq:49 memory:fa8f8000-fa8fffff memory:fa000000-fa7fffff ioport:e100(size=256) ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fa800000-fa8f7fff
```

This is an issue for me as I intend to set up an 8-disk ZFS array, and want to reference the drive's physical location in the system (slot1, slot2, etc).

My intuition tells me that it's an issue with the kernel driver for the C606, but I honestly have no idea.

[EDIT]

If I hotplug the other SATA drives I intend on using on ports 6&7, `/dev/disk/by-path` looks like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000001-lun-0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000002-lun-0 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000003-lun-0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000004-lun-0 -> ../../sdi
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000004-lun-0-part1 -> ../../sdi1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000004-lun-0-part2 -> ../../sdi2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000005-lun-0 -> ../../sdj
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000005-lun-0-part1 -> ../../sdj1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000005-lun-0-part2 -> ../../sdj2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy0-lun-0 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy1-lun-0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0 -> ../../sdi
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0-part1 -> ../../sdi1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0-part2 -> ../../sdi2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy3-lun-0 -> ../../sdj
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy3-lun-0-part1 -> ../../sdj1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy3-lun-0-part2 -> ../../sdj2
```

The portion of the path that previously started with `sas-0x500304801349fe##` has changed to `sas-0x5fcfffff000000##` because I've disabled the Option ROM in the BIOS. But what's interesting here is that `sdd` and `sdf` have disappeared from the `by-path` directory, but `sda`, `sdi`, and `sdj` have appeared. In addition, the order has changed.

Of course, all eight drives show up in the `by-id` directory:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA58PYRS -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LV7KR -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LV87E -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:24 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVJK2 -> ../../sdj
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVJK2-part1 -> ../../sdj1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVJK2-part2 -> ../../sdj2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVL4J -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:24 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVNXX -> ../../sdi
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVNXX-part1 -> ../../sdi1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Oct 17 14:24 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVNXX-part2 -> ../../sdi2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 ata-WDC_WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B0_K1HNL2KD -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 14:20 ata-WDC_WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B0_K1JMY3ND -> ../../sdf
```

[EDIT 2]

The `by-path` directory seems to change with every boot now. It currently looks like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000001-lun-0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000002-lun-0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000003-lun-0 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-0x5fcfffff00000004-lun-0 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy0-lun-0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy1-lun-0 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 pci-0000:03:00.0-sas-phy3-lun-0 -> ../../sdd
```

While the `by-id` path looks like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA58PYRS -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LV7KR -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LV87E -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 ata-WDC_WD6001F9YZ-09YUWL1_WD-WX41DA5LVL4J -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 ata-WDC_WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B0_K1HNL2KD -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 17 15:03 ata-WDC_WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B0_K1JMY3ND -> ../../sdf
```

The disks are consistently assigned the same device ID (sda/sdb/etc), which is reassuring, but the path changes unpredictably (making it completely unusable for my purposes).

[EDIT 3]

The output of `du -a /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:03:00.0 | grep -E 'sd.' | grep -vE 'sd./'` shows the correct mapping for the drives:

```
0   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:03:00.0/host6/port-6:0/end_device-6:0/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sda
0   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:03:00.0/host6/port-6:1/end_device-6:1/target6:0:1/6:0:1:0/block/sdb
0   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:03:00.0/host6/port-6:2/end_device-6:2/target6:0:2/6:0:2:0/block/sdc
0   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:03:00.0/host6/port-6:3/end_device-6:3/target6:0:3/6:0:3:0/block/sdd
0   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:03:00.0/host7/port-7:0/end_device-7:0/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sde
0   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:03:00.0/host7/port-7:1/end_device-7:1/target7:0:1/7:0:1:0/block/sdf
```

So I think this issue is related to a bug in `udev`

Answer (score 1):

I also have a Dell T420 server, and the output of `udevadm info` gives me this:

```
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sdb
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:0:2/0:0:2:0/block/sdc
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:0:3/0:0:3:0/block/sdd
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:0:4/0:0:4:0/block/sde
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:0:5/0:0:5:0/block/sdf
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:0:6/0:0:6:0/block/sdg
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:08:00.0/host0/target0:0:7/0:0:7:0/block/sdh
```

As you can see, there is only on instance of `host#` in the device path (`host0`) whereas the intel SCU has two (`host6` and `host7`). Apparently udev on CentOS 7 doesn't know how to handle this properly, and simply overwrites the device links (so any device under the `host6` node gets its symlink in `/dev/disks/by-path` overwritten by the corresponding device under the `host7` node).

Looks like I need learn how to write udev rules now....

[EDIT]

Initial attempt at a udev rule to solve the problem: https://gist.github.com/dghodgson/49da6175371cdde317e662fb8a7d078a

It's very ugly and buggy. Doesn't handle hot-plugging properly at all, and doesn't do anything with partitions. I need to find a way to create the updated properties from existing info instead of editing them in-place, otherwise there's a chance of the paths changing every time the udev rules are reloaded.

[EDIT 2]

Gist has been updated to output paths similar to what's produced by the `handle_scsi_default` function in the `path_id` builtin. It's much, much more reliable now, and also handles partitions. Hopefully someone else will also find it useful. It's still a hack though, so YMMV.

Currently working to get a proper fix patched into udev.